# How can i change the content of a modal without closing it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal that opens up when i click a button, the thing is that i have 2 buttons that open the same modal but with different contents, so if i click the same button when the modal is opened, it'll close. That's workin' fine, what i wanna do, and can't do, is change the content of the modal without closing it when i click the  button that doesn't opened it. Can anyone help me with this? That's the code i'm using:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>EA - Need for Speed Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <nav class="menu-togglers is-visible">
      <ul>
        <li class="dropdown-toggler account" id="account"><i class="far fa-user"></i></li>
        <li class="dropdown-toggler help" id="help"><i class="fas fa-question"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--menu-togglers-->

    <div class="dropdown-menu is-not-collapsed" id="dropdown-menu">

      <img id="close-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggler" src="assets/x-lg.svg">

      <div class="account-container menu-container opacity-0">
        <div id="account-item" class="menu-content">
          <a href="">
            <img src="assets/connectEA.svg" alt="">
            <p>Sign In</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!--account-item-->

        <div id="account-item" class="menu-content">
          <a href="">
            <img src="assets/createAccountEA.svg" alt="">
            <p>Create Account</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!--account-item-->
      </div>
      <!--account-container-->

      <div class="help-container menu-container opacity-0">
        <div id="help-item" class="menu-content">
          <a href="">
            <img src="assets/originIcon.svg" alt="">
            <p>Verify my Origin Login</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!--help-item-->

        <div id="help-item" class="menu-content">
          <a href="">
            <img src="assets/linkAccount.svg" alt="">
            <p>Link my Origin to my PSN ID</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!--help-item-->

        <div id="help-item" class="menu-content">
          <a href="">
            <img src="assets/rescueCode.svg" alt="">
            <p>How do I redeem a Code?</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!--help-item-->

        <div id="help-item" class="menu-content">
          <a href="">
            <img src="assets/errorIcon.svg" alt="">
            <p>I can't play online!</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!--help-item-->
      </div>
      <!--account-container-->

    </div>
    <!--dropdown-menu-->

  </header>
  <!--header-->

  <div style="height: 2000px;"></div>

  <script src="js/hideHeader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/setMenus.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <title>EA - Need for Speed Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.4.1/lity.css" integrity="sha512-NDcw4w5Uk5nra1mdgmYYbghnm2azNRbxeI63fd3Zw72aYzFYdBGgODILLl1tHZezbC8Kep/Ep/civILr5nd1Qw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <style>
  .modalDialog{
  width: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50%;
    background: white;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding: 50px;
    max-width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
  }
  .modalcont{font-size:16px; color:black;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="button">
        <a class="modalopen" href="javascript:void(0);" datacontent="testingone">modal open</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--header-->
<footer>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" style="display:none;">
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <div class="modalcont">testingone</div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn"  datacontent="testingone">button one</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn"  datacontent="testingtwo">button two</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        
        jQuery('.modalopen').on('click',function(){
            var sun = jQuery(this).attr('datacontent');
            jQuery('#openModal').show(500);
            jQuery('#openModal .modalcont').html(''+sun+'');
            //alert(sun);
        });
        jQuery('.btn').on('click',function(){
            var sun = jQuery(this).attr('datacontent');
            //alert(sun);
            jQuery('#openModal .modalcont').html(sun);
            //alert(sun);
        });
        jQuery('.close').on('click',function(){
            jQuery('#openModal').hide(500);
            jQuery('#openModal .modalcont').html();
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's almost that, but in my problem, the button that opens and closes the modal is the same that changes the content if the content related to the other button is showing. And this is the bahavior fot both of the buttons.

Comment: It's like the buttons in the header navigation in the ea page: https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed